Linear dependency between features on unsupervised learning
I am preparing a numerical dataset to be trained using unsupervised learning methods (i.e. association with Apriori algorithm) in order to try to find instrinsic correlations hidden in the data. Initially I thought about adding some artificial features based on manual calculations I would do, based on the other existing features. For example, creating the average value or variance of some relevant features that would have a real meaning in the real world. However, algorithms like the Apriori algorithm is said to search not only for possible patterns/correlations between features but also between feature sets. But I do not really know how this is really being done mathematically. Example:
Let's say we are talking about a customer profile as input data and have the following features:
feature1: monthly spent money (average)
feature2: amount of money spent on first purchase
feature3: customer has ever donated money to charity (yes/no)
And let's say our model finds out that a certain pattern exists, where customers that usually spent a montly average of around 50\$ and had a first purchased of around 25\$, are usually the ones that also donate money to a charity at some point. However, I might raise the question, if customers whose monthly spent money that is 2x the amount of money spent on the first purchase, are usually the ones that tend to donate money (or to find out any relationship between the ration feature1/feature2 and feature3). In other words, if the relation "feature3 tends to be True when feature1 = 2x feature2" applies. So I could artificially create a feature4 being the ratio feature1/feature2 and see if the network might find the relationship between feature3 tending to be True when feature4 gets around 2 (or if there is any important ration between feature1 and feature2 that maximizes the chance of feature3 being True).
Considering the example above, my question would be: does it make sense to create this extra feature to analyze this possible relationship or does the Apriori algorithm (or any similar) already checks for such relations when grouping the features during learning (since grouping features does not necessarily means making calculations using this group)?
